# Pandas Groupby Range of Values

Tags: python, group-by, pandas

Is there an easy method in pandas to invoke `groupby` on a range of values increments? For instance given the example below can I bin and group column `B` with a `0.155` increment so that for example, the first couple of groups in column `B` are divided into ranges between '0 - 0.155, 0.155 - 0.31 ...`

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':np.random.random(20),'B':np.random.random(20)})

     A         B
0  0.383493  0.250785
1  0.572949  0.139555
2  0.652391  0.401983
3  0.214145  0.696935
4  0.848551  0.516692
```

Alternatively I could first categorize the data by those increments into a new column and subsequently use `groupby` to determine any relevant statistics that may be applicable in column `A`?

Answer (score 189, accepted):

You might be interested in [`pd.cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html):

```
>>> df.groupby(pd.cut(df["B"], np.arange(0, 1.0+0.155, 0.155))).sum()
                      A         B
B                                
(0, 0.155]     2.775458  0.246394
(0.155, 0.31]  1.123989  0.471618
(0.31, 0.465]  2.051814  1.882763
(0.465, 0.62]  2.277960  1.528492
(0.62, 0.775]  1.577419  2.810723
(0.775, 0.93]  0.535100  1.694955
(0.93, 1.085]       NaN       NaN

[7 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: Is it possible for me to do this for multiple dimensions? Essentially grouping by two values simultaneously?

Comment: I had to group using 2 columns. First column was a string and I had to group rows with same names. Among these group, I had to further group them based on range of values in the second column. I did it as follows: `(qa_scores_data.groupby(['Video Name', pandas.cut(qa_scores_data['Frame Name'].astype('float'), [0.5, 12.5, 24.5, 36.5, 48.5])])).mean()`

Comment: I'll get this error: `ValueError: Length of grouper (9235) and axis (8769) must be same length`

Comment: The first range of B is (0, 0.155) while the first row of B is 0.246394 > 0.155,  I suppose 0.246394 should be fallen into second range(0.155, 0.31]. No ?

Comment: @JacquelineP. the `.sum()` function at the end are adding all of the numbers between (0, 0.155] to get the numbers you're seeing.

Comment: I'd also like to point out that the `np.arrange()` while fully functional may be overkill as a simple list works just as well (haven't tested performance for large sets).

Answer (score 19):

Try this:

```py
df = df.sort_values('B')
bins =  np.arange(0, 1.0, 0.155)
ind = np.digitize(df['B'], bins)
    
print df.groupby(ind).head()
```

Of course you can use any function on the groups not just `head`.

Comment: What if the first value of B in the group is needed with average of other corresponding columns?

Answer (score 2):

so this is how I use the groupby function

```
df1=data
bins = [0,40,50,60,70,100]
group_names=['F','S','C','B','A']
df1['grade']=pd.cut(data['student_mark'],bins,labels=group_names)
df1
```