# Pandas calculate number of values between each range

Tags: python, pandas

I want to find counts of my data between certain custom ranges.

Say I have some data:

```
import random

my_randoms = random.sample(xrange(100), 10)        
test = pd.DataFrame(my_randoms,columns = ["x"])
```

How can I produce a data frame that shows the number of values between different ranges? For example, say I want to see how many values occur between 0-19, 20-39, 40-59, 60-79, 80-100. The output dataframe will have one column with those ranges, another with the counts.

I can think of some ugly approaches that involve use of .apply to get a new column list saying which value they are between (and then doing a groupby), but I suspect pandas has a cleaner way lurking about.

Comment: [Pandas Groupby Range of Values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21441259/pandas-groupby-range-of-values) might help.

Comment: that worked! too easy as usual

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Per Jarad's link to that other question:

```
test.groupby(pd.cut(test['x'], np.arange(0,100,20))).count()
```

Answer (score 2):

there's probably a better way. I'm only new to pandas myself but how about this for the moment:

```
test.query(test.x.isin(range(20)))
```

Answer (score 1):

pandas and numpy allow **boolean index**,
is this an ugly approach?

```
ranges = [ (0,19), (20, 39), (40, 69) ...]
cnt = []
for range in ranges:
    tmp = ranges[(ranges['x'] > range[0]) & (range['x'] <= range[1]) ]
    cnt.append( len(tmp) )
```

Comment: I suddenly remembered the `numpy.histogram` solution. It is better than this I think.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `numpy.histrogram` function.

```
import numpy as np
series = [0, 20, 40, ...]
count, bin_edge = np.histogram( bins = series )
```

According to [numpy.histogram](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html), if `bins` is a sequence, it defines the bin edges, including the rightmost edge, allowing for non-uniform bin widths.