# How to group by a range of values in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `dataframe`, which I want to group by categorical variables and a range of values. You may think of it like rows of similar values (clusters?). E.g:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'symbol' : ['IP', 'IP', 'IP', 'IP', 'IP', 'IP', 'IP'],
                   'serie' : ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'B'],
                   'strike' : [10, 10, 12, 13, 12, 13, 14],
                   'last' : [1, 2, 2.5, 3, 4.5, 5, 6],
                   'price' : [11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11],
                   'type' : ['call', 'put', 'put', 'put', 'call', 'put', 'call']})
```

If I use

```
grouped = df.groupby(['symbol', 'serie', 'strike'])
```

I have part of my problem solved, but I want to combine the strike values that are closer, such as 10 and 11, 12 and 13 and so forth. Preferably within a % range.

Comment: seems duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21441259/pandas-groupby-range-of-values

Comment: May you show an expected output please?

Comment: You need a well defined criterion for clustering/grouping the strike values first.

Comment: I think creating a column with balanced bins and grouping by the new bin-column together with other columns should work.

Comment: Not entirely clear what you want to group and how. Could you show your desired result?

Comment: Thanks all, in fact I want to identify the lines where the strikes values are close to the price values. So 10 and 12 are the closest strikes to the price (11). Next step would be to set variable and control how close them should be. The result can be just another column with false/true or bin level as suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing OP wants to group by categorical variables, followed by a numeric variable binned in intervals. In that case you can use the `np.digitize()`.

```
smallest = np.min(df['strike'])
largest = np.max(df['strike'])
num_edges = 3
# np.digitize(input_array, bin_edges)
ind = np.digitize(df['strike'], np.linspace(smallest, largest, num_edges))
```

then `ind` should be

```
array([1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3], dtype=int64)
```

which corresponding to binning

```
 [10, 10, 12, 13, 12, 13, 14]
```

with bin edges

```
array([ 10.,  12.,  14.]) # == np.linspace(smallest, largest, num_edges)
```

Finally, group by all the columns you want, but with this additional bin column

```
df['binned_strike'] = ind
for grp in df.groupby(['symbol', 'serie', 'binned_strike']):
    print "group key"
    print grp[0]
    print "group content"
    print grp[1]
    print "============="
```

This should print

```
group key
('IP', 'A', 1)
group content
   last  price serie  strike symbol  type  binned_strike
0   1.0     11     A      10     IP  call              1
=============
group key
('IP', 'A', 2)
group content
   last  price serie  strike symbol  type  binned_strike
2   2.5     11     A      12     IP   put              2
4   4.5     11     A      12     IP  call              2
=============
group key
('IP', 'B', 1)
group content
   last  price serie  strike symbol type  binned_strike
1   2.0     11     B      10     IP  put              1
=============
group key
('IP', 'B', 2)
group content
   last  price serie  strike symbol type  binned_strike
3   3.0     11     B      13     IP  put              2
5   5.0     11     B      13     IP  put              2
=============
group key
('IP', 'B', 3)
group content
   last  price serie  strike symbol  type  binned_strike
6   6.0     11     B      14     IP  call              3
=============
```

Answer (score 2):

## Do `groupy()` on *bins* of `strike`

Create bins of strike data with [`pd.cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html), and then group by that information:

```
# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'symbol' : ['IP', 'IP', 'IP', 'IP', 'IP', 'IP', 'IP'],
    'serie' : ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'B'],
    'strike' : [10, 10, 12, 13, 12, 13, 14],
    'last' : [1, 2, 2.5, 3, 4.5, 5, 6],
    'price' : [11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11],
    'type' : ['call', 'put', 'put', 'put', 'call', 'put', 'call']
})
# Create Bins (example three bins across data)
df['strikebins'] = pd.cut(df['strike'], bins=3)

print 'Binned DataFrame:'
print df
print

# Group these DataFrame
grouped = df.groupby(['symbol', 'serie', 'strikebins'])

# Do something with groups for example
gp_sum = grouped.sum()

print 'Grouped Sum (for example):'
print gp_sum
print
```

---

```
Binned DataFrame:
   last  price serie  strike symbol  type        strikebins
0   1.0     11     A      10     IP  call   (9.996, 11.333]
1   2.0     11     B      10     IP   put   (9.996, 11.333]
2   2.5     11     A      12     IP   put  (11.333, 12.667]
3   3.0     11     B      13     IP   put      (12.667, 14]
4   4.5     11     A      12     IP  call  (11.333, 12.667]
5   5.0     11     B      13     IP   put      (12.667, 14]
6   6.0     11     B      14     IP  call      (12.667, 14]

Grouped Sum (for example):
                               last  price  strike
symbol serie strikebins                           
IP     A     (9.996, 11.333]      1     11      10
             (11.333, 12.667]     7     22      24
             (12.667, 14]       NaN    NaN     NaN
       B     (9.996, 11.333]      2     11      10
             (11.333, 12.667]   NaN    NaN     NaN
             (12.667, 14]        14     33      40
```

You could `drop()` `strike` if you wanted, or replace `strikebins` with the mean of the range...