# Using Pandas how do I count groups of data?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, histogram

I have a large dataframe:

```
      peak.count  purity.score material  
0           10.0      0.134814      ADB  
1           10.0      0.134814      ADB  
2           17.0      0.116754      ADB  
3           17.0      0.116754      ADB  
4           17.0      0.102921      ADB   
...          ...           ...      ...  
1269        14.0      0.166039      SSA  
1270        14.0      0.166039      SSA  
1271        14.0      0.166039      SSA  
1272        12.0      0.169396      SSA  
1273        12.0      0.169396      SSA  
1274        12.0      0.169396      SSA
```

I'm curious about grouping the purity.score by a range and then counting those values within the ranges. For example, if 15 of my values fall between 0.1 and 0.2 I would like the output to reflect 15 at 1. I have tried something that uses value_counts in conjunction with a numpy range, but does not count the values within the groups:

First I do this: `s = pd.Series(df['purity.score'])`

```
pd.value_counts(s).reindex(np.arange(0,1,0.1)).fillna(0)
0.0    362.0
0.1      0.0
0.2      0.0
0.3      0.0
0.4      0.0
0.5      0.0
0.6      0.0
0.7      0.0
0.8      0.0
0.9      0.0
```

How can I group these values? Note I wish to use this table to feed an API in order to render a javascript histogram, but do not wish to use Bokeh or Matplotlib. I need access to the table.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21441259/pandas-groupby-range-of-values .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with the [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html) function:

```
df.groupby(pd.cut(df['purity.score'], bins=10)).count()
```

Here, `cut` is dividing `df['purity.score']` into 10 bins of its choice, but you can define the bin boundaries by passing an array.

Comment: cut is exactly what I need! Thanks : )

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is probably the groupby function. To group by ranges of size 0.1 you could do this (the dataframe is called `df` here)

```
 df['purity.score'].groupby((df['purity.score']*10).astype(int)).count()
```

the argument here is the purity.score column, multiplied by 10, and then converted to int - an operation which maps [0.1-0.2) -> 1, [0.2, 0.3) -> 2 etc. Not very pretty, but it works.