# Pandas - group by consecutive ranges

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, intervals

I have a dataframe with the following structure - Start, End and Height.

Some properties of the dataframe:

- A row in the dataframe always starts from where the previous row ended i.e. if the end for row n is 100 then the start of line n+1 is 101.
- The height of row n+1 is always different then the height in row n+1 (this is the reason the data is in different rows).

I'd like to group the dataframe in a way that heights will be grouped in buckets of 5 longs i.e. the buckets are *0, 1-5, 6-10, 11-15 and >15*.

See code example below where what I'm looking for is the implemetation of *group_by_bucket* function.

I tried looking at other questions but couldn't get exact answer to what I was looking for.

Thanks in advance!

```
>>> d = pd.DataFrame([[1,3,5], [4,10,7], [11,17,6], [18,26, 12], [27,30, 15], [31,40,6], [41, 42, 7]], columns=['start','end', 'height'])
>>> d
   start  end  height
0      1    3       8
1      4   10       7
2     11   17       6
3     18   26      12
4     27   30      15
5     31   40       6
6     41   42       7
>>> d_gb = group_by_bucket(d)
>>> d_gb
   start  end height_grouped
0      1   17           6_10
1     18   30          11_15
2     31   42           6_10
```

Comment: Isn't this a dupe of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21441259/pandas-groupby-range-of-values?lq=1? in your case you want to call `cut` on 'height' and pass a range, something like `pd.cut(d['height'], bins=np.arange(1, d['height'].max()+1, 5))`

Comment: In your example `height_grouped` values are not unique. `d_gb` has three groups but two of them are the same so you should have an additional grouping criterion that you didn't mention.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A way to do that :

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,3,10], [4,10,7], [11,17,6], [18,26, 12],
[27,30, 15], [31,40,6], [41, 42, 6]], columns=['start','end', 'height'])
```

Use `cut` to make groups :

```
df['groups']=pd.cut(df.height,[-1,0,5,10,15,1000])
```

Find break points :

```
df['categories']=(df.groups!=df.groups.shift()).cumsum()
```

Then `df` is :

```
"""
   start  end  height    groups  categories
0      1    3      10   (5, 10]           0
1      4   10       7   (5, 10]           0
2     11   17       6   (5, 10]           0
3     18   26      12  (10, 15]           1
4     27   30      15  (10, 15]           1
5     31   40       6   (5, 10]           2
6     41   42       6   (5, 10]           2
"""
```

Define interesting data :

```
f = {'start':['first'],'end':['last'], 'groups':['first']}
```

And use the `groupby.agg` function :

```
df.groupby('categories').agg(f)
"""
              groups  end start
               first last first
categories                     
0            (5, 10]   17     1
1           (10, 15]   30    18
2            (5, 10]   42    31
"""
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html) with [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by `cut` and `Series` with `cumsum` for generating groups and aggregate by [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html), [`first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) and [`last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html):

```
bins = [-1,0,1,5,10,15,100]
print bins
[-1, 0, 1, 5, 10, 15, 100]

cut_ser = pd.cut(d['height'], bins=bins)
print cut_ser
0     (5, 10]
1     (5, 10]
2     (5, 10]
3    (10, 15]
4    (10, 15]
5     (5, 10]
6     (5, 10]
Name: height, dtype: category
Categories (6, object): [(-1, 0] < (0, 1] < (1, 5] < (5, 10] < (10, 15] < (15, 100]]

print (cut_ser.shift() != cut_ser).cumsum()
0    0
1    0
2    0
3    1
4    1
5    2
6    2
Name: height, dtype: int32

print d.groupby([(cut_ser.shift() != cut_ser).cumsum(), cut_ser])
       .agg({'start' : 'first','end' : 'last'})
       .reset_index(level=1).reset_index(drop=True)
       .rename(columns={'height':'height_grouped'})

  height_grouped  start  end
0        (5, 10]      1   17
1       (10, 15]     18   30
2        (5, 10]     31   42
```

EDIT:

**Timings**:

```
In [307]: %timeit a(df)
100 loops, best of 3: 5.45 ms per loop

In [308]: %timeit b(d)
The slowest run took 4.45 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
100 loops, best of 3: 3.28 ms per loop
```

**Code**:

```
d = pd.DataFrame([[1,3,5], [4,10,7], [11,17,6], [18,26, 12], [27,30, 15], [31,40,6], [41, 42, 7]], columns=['start','end', 'height'])
print d

df = d.copy()


def a(df):
    df['groups']=pd.cut(df.height,[-1,0,5,10,15,1000])
    df['categories']=(df.groups!=df.groups.shift()).cumsum()
    f = {'start':['first'],'end':['last'], 'groups':['first']}
    return df.groupby('categories').agg(f)

def b(d):
    bins = [-1,0,1,5,10,15,100]
    cut_ser = pd.cut(d['height'], bins=bins)
    return d.groupby([(cut_ser.shift() != cut_ser).cumsum(), cut_ser]).agg({'start' : 'first','end' : 'last'}).reset_index(level=1).reset_index(drop=True).rename(columns={'height':'height_grouped'})


print a(df)    
print b(d)
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems like a similar solution to B.M.. Both seems to do the trick

Comment: Yes, it looks similar, but my solution is 1.6 times faster.