# Pandas groupby for range of time strings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, binning

I have a `pandas` dataframe (stored in a `.csv` file) with the following format.

```
val,date,time
0.001,01JAN90,0:00:00
0.002,01JAN90,0:01:00
0.005,01JAN90,0:02:00
0.056,01JAN90,0:03:00
...
0.067,31DEC90,23:55:00
0.007,31DEC90,23:56:00
0.006,31DEC90,23:57:00
0.004,31DEC90,23:58:00
0.003,31DEC90,23:59:00
```

This is: a single float (`val` column) for each minute (`time` column) of each day (`time` column) in a year. I need to group the `val` elements throughout the entire year, that belong to a given hour range. I define 15 hour ranges as:

```
t_range = [['5:30:00', '6:30:00'], ['6:30:00', '7:30:00'], ...,
['19:30:00', '20:30:00']]
```

The answer given here [Pandas Groupby Range of Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21441259/pandas-groupby-range-of-values?noredirect=1&lq=1) deals with ranges defined as floats, but my ranges are defined as strings.

My idea is that I'd need to first convert all the HH:MM:SS values in `time` to floats, and then apply the solution based on [groupby](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) and [pd.cut](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html). Is this the proper approach? How should I be using `pandas` to do this if not?

Comment: Can you be sure that you have data at minutes frequency?

Comment: You mean if any rows are missing? I'm sure there are not, the length of the columns is exactly (N days in year)*(24 hs)*(60 mins)

Comment: Then I guess a simple approach is to rely on the number of observations (1h = 60 obs). If you define a dummy variable "count" 1,2,3... you can use modulo to understand in which range you are and then use group bt

Comment: You are correct, but I'd prefer a general solution that does not make this assumption.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC you can do it this way:

```
start = 5*60+30
end = 20*60+30
step = 60

df['ts'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date + ' ' + df.time, format='%d%b%y %H:%M:%S')
df['mins'] = df.ts.dt.hour*60 + df.ts.dt.minute

# filter out all "non-interesting" entries                           
x = df.query("@start <= mins <= @end")

bins = np.arange(start-step, end+step, step)
labels = ['({0[0]:02d}:{0[1]:02d}:00, {0[0]:02d}:{0[1]:02d}:00]'.format(divmod(x,60),
                                                                        divmod(x+step,60))
          for x in bins[:-1]]


x.groupby(pd.cut(x['mins'], bins=bins, labels=labels))['val'].sum().dropna()
```

Result:

```
In [164]: x.groupby(pd.cut(x['mins'], bins=bins, labels=labels))['val'].sum().dropna()
Out[164]:
mins
(05:30:00, 06:30:00]    0.006
(06:30:00, 07:30:00]    0.004
(07:30:00, 08:30:00]    0.003
(08:30:00, 09:30:00]    0.111
(09:30:00, 10:30:00]    0.001
(10:30:00, 11:30:00]    0.002
(11:30:00, 12:30:00]    0.005
(12:30:00, 13:30:00]    0.056
Name: val, dtype: float64
```

Source DF:

```
In [166]: df
Out[166]:
     val     date      time
0  0.067  01DEC90  04:00:00
1  0.007  01DEC90  05:00:00
2  0.006  01DEC90  06:00:00
3  0.004  01DEC90  07:00:00
4  0.003  01DEC90  08:00:00
5  0.111  01DEC90  09:00:00
6  0.001  01JAN90  10:00:00
7  0.002  01JAN90  11:00:00
8  0.005  01JAN90  12:00:00
9  0.056  01JAN90  13:00:00
```

Explanation:

bins: # of minutes

```
In [181]: bins
Out[181]: array([ 270,  330,  390,  450,  510,  570,  630,  690,  750,  810,  870,  930,  990, 1050, 1110, 1170, 1230])
```

labels

```
In [182]: labels
Out[182]:
['(04:30:00, 04:30:00]',
 '(05:30:00, 05:30:00]',
 '(06:30:00, 06:30:00]',
 '(07:30:00, 07:30:00]',
 '(08:30:00, 08:30:00]',
 '(09:30:00, 09:30:00]',
 '(10:30:00, 10:30:00]',
 '(11:30:00, 11:30:00]',
 '(12:30:00, 12:30:00]',
 '(13:30:00, 13:30:00]',
 '(14:30:00, 14:30:00]',
 '(15:30:00, 15:30:00]',
 '(16:30:00, 16:30:00]',
 '(17:30:00, 17:30:00]',
 '(18:30:00, 18:30:00]',
 '(19:30:00, 19:30:00]']
```