# Pandas filtering / data reduction (1) is there a better way and 2) what am I doing wrong)

Tags: python, pandas

What I'm trying to do is read in a csv, eliminate duplicate values based on a specific column, then reduce the data to not have a point any more close together than an increment of 15.

My code reads in the file fine, then the drop_duplicates works as required, then I sort it by that column. In order to reduce the data, I'm creating a new dataframe with the first row from the existing one, then I'm going through every value in the column in question and appending it to the new dataframe if it's at least 15 kg/hr higher than the comparison value.

My dataframe isn't combining correctly and I'm ending up with a resultant dataframe that is arranged like this:

```
Unnamed: 0                                                                     0
TimeStamp (s)                                                              0.002
TC 01 (C)                                                                30.6689
TC 02 (C)                                                                28.6879
TC 03 (C)                                                                27.9779
TC 32 (C)                                                                22.6416
Product Back Pressure (kPa)                                             0.166353
Product Mass Flow (kg/hr)                                                107.427
Semtech Flow (kg/hr)                                                     28.2135
Mass Flow (kg/hr)                                                        28.2135
Voltage (V)                                                              1.63065
Angle (degrees)                                                                0
1                                 Unnamed: 0  TimeStamp (s)  TC 01 (C)  TC 02...
2                                  Unnamed: 0  TimeStamp (s)  TC 01 (C)  TC 0...
3                                 Unnamed: 0  TimeStamp (s)  TC 01 (C)  TC 02...
4                                 Unnamed: 0  TimeStamp (s)  TC 01 (C)  TC 02...
```

I'm clearly doing something wrong, but at least it's less wrong than when I tried appending within the "if" statement.

```
 def import_df():
    new_df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(pathname, f), delimiter = ',')
    new_df = new_df.drop_duplicates(subset = 'Mass Flow (kg/hr)')
    new_df = new_df.sort_values('Mass Flow (kg/hr)')
    reduced_df = new_df.iloc[0]
    current_mass_flow = new_df['Mass Flow (kg/hr)'].iloc[0]
    i = 1
    for value in new_df['Mass Flow (kg/hr)']:
        if value < current_mass_flow + 15:
            reduced_df.loc[i] = new_df.loc[new_df['Mass Flow (kg/hr)'] == value]
            current_mass_flow = value
            i += 1
        else: next

    return reduced_df
```

What can I do to correct this? It's clearly not adding to the dataframe the way I expect it to. I'm definitely missing some finer points on how to add a row to this dataframe.

Also, I can't help but feel that there's a much simpler / more direct way to accomplish what I'm trying to do.

```
Sample Source Data 

    TimeStamp (s)   TC 01 (C)   TC 02 (C)   TC 03 (C)   TC 32 (C)   Product Back Pressure (kPa) Product Mass Flow (kg/hr)   Semtech Flow (kg/hr)    Mass Flow (kg/hr)   Voltage (V) Angle (degrees)
0   0.004   493.2881108 296.1245877 255.8202916 26.3430426  0.297276487 147.4692621 30.21243527 30.21243527 1.634457337 0
1   0.178   493.2881108 296.1245877 255.8202916 26.3430426  0.283227103 147.4692621 30.21243527 30.21243527 1.634457337 0
2   1.178   493.1325481 296.155699  255.8514043 26.3430426  0.283227103 144.5363918 31.06903075 31.06903075 1.634457337 0
3   2.178   493.0703231 296.2490329 255.8825171 26.3430426  0.289335716 141.244467  31.06903075 31.06903075 1.634457337 0
4   3.178   492.4480726 296.373478  255.8825171 26.40525146 0.292389668 141.244467  29.73651711 29.73651711 1.634139868 0
5   4.178   493.2881108 296.373478  255.9136299 26.3430426  0.292389668 146.0926428 30.40291693 30.40291693 1.634457337 0
6   5.178   493.2881108 296.4357006 255.8825171 26.40525146 0.289742626 146.0926428 30.40291693 30.40291693 1.634457337 0
7   6.178   492.8836479 296.4045893 255.9136299 26.40525146 0.281191135 146.0926428 30.78359426 30.78359426 1.634139868 0
8   7.178   493.1325481 296.373478  255.9447427 26.40525146 0.281191135 146.2123624 30.02223961 30.02223961 1.634457337 0
90  959.629 442.3250036 300.5424521 264.6564452 27.77387677 0.593127726 203.9719224 44.39531112 44.39531112 1.635409746 0
91  960.629 442.231666  300.5424521 264.6564452 27.77387677 0.599643603 203.9719224 44.77598845 44.77598845 1.634457337 0
92  961.629 441.3605153 300.3557844 264.6564452 27.77387677 0.58966651  199.4828012 44.77598845 44.77598845 1.634457337 0
93  962.629 441.0493901 300.3557844 264.6253324 27.77387677 0.58966651  199.1237467 43.63367047 43.63367047 1.634774807 0
94  963.629 441.0493901 300.1691166 264.531994  27.77387677 0.58885198  199.1237467 43.63367047 43.63367047 1.635092276 0
95  964.629 441.2360652 300.3868956 264.531994  27.77387677 0.588444716 203.8522028 43.63367047 43.63367047 1.635092276 0
96  965.629 441.4849654 300.3557844 264.4697685 27.77387677 0.588444716 199.1237467 43.63367047 43.63367047 1.634139868 0
97  966.629 441.3916279 300.2935618 264.4697685 27.77387677 0.597403826 199.1237467 44.39531112 44.39531112 1.633823352 0
98  967.629 441.7338656 300.4802295 264.531994  27.77387677 0.592720461 203.8522028 44.39531112 44.39531112 1.634139868 0
99  968.629 441.2982903 300.6046747 264.6253324 27.77387677 0.592720461 203.9719224 43.63367047 43.63367047 1.634139868 0
100 969.629 441.578303  300.6980086 264.687558  27.77387677 0.606769845 203.9719224 45.06142494 45.06142494 1.634139868 0
101 970.629 441.8894282 300.5735634 264.687558  27.77387677 0.594145709 200.3806463 45.06142494 45.06142494 1.635092276 0
```

Desired Output

```
TimeStamp (s)   TC 01 (C)   TC 02 (C)   TC 03 (C)   TC 32 (C)   Product Back Pressure (kPa) Product Mass Flow (kg/hr)   Semtech Flow (kg/hr)    Mass Flow (kg/hr)   Voltage (V) Angle (degrees)
13  12.178  493.008098  296.2490329 255.8825171 26.3430426  0.31682341  146.0327308 29.26059896 29.26059896 1.634139868 0
77  947.156 443.7872922 301.3202954 264.9986859 27.74277234 0.613081913 199.8419601 44.39531112 44.39531112 1.637947595 0.158889819
```

Comment: can you add sample source data and expected output

Comment: Added some sample data

Comment: I agree with Phik. The difference between the maximum and minimum values in that column is only 15, and if you eliminate data rows you could be losing considerable information.

Comment: I only chose a chunk of the data, the range does go up to about 900 (that's part of why the index jumped)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this code and let me know if you are looking for this. 
[pandas.DataFrame.iterrows](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html)  is used to looping through the records and to check the mass flow.

> pandas.DataFrame.iterrows --- A generator that iterates over the rows of the frame.

```
import pandas as pd
import os 
new_df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join('C:\Shijo\Python\sample.txt'), delimiter = ',')
new_df = new_df.drop_duplicates(subset = 'Mass Flow (kg/hr)')
new_df = new_df.sort_values('Mass Flow (kg/hr)')
new_df = new_df.reset_index(drop=True)
current_mass_flow = new_df.iloc[0]['Mass Flow (kg/hr)']

indexlst=[1]

for index, row in new_df.iterrows():

    if row['Mass Flow (kg/hr)'] > current_mass_flow + 15:
        print ("Mathcing index : ",index)
        indexlst.append(index)
        current_mass_flow =row['Mass Flow (kg/hr)']


reduced_df= new_df.iloc[indexlst]
print (reduced_df )
```

output

```
   TimeStamp (s)   TC 01 (C)   TC 02 (C)   TC 03 (C)  TC 32 (C)  Product Back Pressure (kPa)  Product Mass Flow (kg/hr)    Semtech Flow (kg/hr)  Mass Flow (kg/hr)  Voltage (V)  Angle (degrees)   
1          7.178  493.132548  296.373478  255.944743  26.405251                     0.281191                 146.212362               30.022240          30.022240     1.634457                 0  
8        960.629  442.231666  300.542452  264.656445  27.773877                     0.599644                 203.971922               44.775988          44.775988     1.634457                 0
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are looking for [pandas.cut](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/generated/pandas.cut.html), where you would specify the bins (with `np.arange` for example). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21441259/pandas-groupby-range-of-values) for example.

---

EDIT:
With a `groupby` and `cut`

```
new_df.groupby(pd.cut(new_df['Mass Flow (kg/hr)'],\
                  np.arange(new_df['Mass Flow (kg/hr)'].min(),
                           new_df['Mass Flow (kg/hr)'].max()+1,
                           15)))\
.apply(lambda x: x.loc[x['Mass Flow (kg/hr)'].idxmin()])
```

Comment: I don't understand how that would reduce the amount of data that I have, at all. I do literally want to cut that chunk of data down to those 2 points - the actual dataset is about 2000 lines and I only need a fraction of it. I either need to correct what my loop is doing so that the format of the dataframe isn't completely messed up or have an alternative to using the loop at all.

Answer (score 0):

Appart from the duplicate removal, wouldn't it be interesting to split your data into "reproducible" bins?

```python
df['bins'] = df['Mass Flow (kg/hr)'] // 15                        # Create bins from 0
df.groupby(['bins'], as_index=False).mean().drop('bins', axis=1)  # Get mean values
                                                                  # and remove "bin" column
```

Otherwise you can apply the same process with normalization in respect to the minimum value of the series.

```python
df['bins'] = (df['Mass Flow (kg/hr)'] - df['Mass Flow (kg/hr)'].min()) // 15  # Normalized bins
df.groupby(['bins'], as_index=False).mean().drop('bins', axis=1)
```

Note that this code was tested on your data directly (unusable with `pandas.read_clipboard()`), but works on a "similar" dataframe.