# Get indices of fully open bins in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to get indices of **fully open bins** in pandas?

 e.g.   (0,10),(10,20),(20,30) instead of  (0,10],(10,20],(20,30] 
 As per the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html) pandas.cut returns indices of half-open bins.

Comment: It is the default, and returns half-open bins. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21441259/pandas-groupby-range-of-values

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It would lead for a workaround. But I found no direct way yet. It does not make a difference...still returns half-open bins, yet decides whether the bins include the rightmost edge or not.

Comment: Sorry for misleading you, I will delete the comment. Cuts usually offer only half open bins, Will answer as soon as I figure out the method ;)

Comment: Thanks you Dark! I am also searching.

Comment: So you dont want to include 10,20,30 and why is that?

Comment: I am trying to do some sampling on a data set to do some calculations. I am interested in [0,10],[10,20],[20,30] scenario as well.

Comment: For closed bins just use `include_lowest = true`,  though you will get half open bins, it will work as closed bins.