# How to group pandas dataframe rows per range of date

Tags: python, pandas

This is my first step with pandas and data manipulation. 
I got basketball games statistics from kaggle (https://www.kaggle.com/pablote/nba-enhanced-stats). the dataset contains a datetime columns going from oct 31 2012 to oct 31 2018.

I'd like to group my rows per date range (nba season to be more precise), that means I'd have:
- 1st group from oct 31 2012 to july 31 2013
- 2nd group from oct 31 2013 to july 31 2014 and so on till
- nth group from oct 21 2017 to july 31 2018.

I read some thread mentioning groupby, date range but I'm not sure if this would work in my case.

Below is the code (jupyter notebook) I'm using right now

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv('2012-18_teamBoxScore.csv')
df1.shape, df1.keys()
    ((14758, 123),
     Index(['gmDate', 'gmTime', 'seasTyp', 'offLNm1', 'offFNm1', 'offLNm2',
    'offFNm2', 'offLNm3', 'offFNm3', 'teamAbbr',
    ...
    'opptFIC40', 'opptOrtg', 'opptDrtg', 'opptEDiff', 'opptPlay%', 'opptAR',
    'opptAST/TO', 'opptSTL/TO', 'poss', 'pace'],
    dtype='object', length=123))
df1['gmDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['gmDate'])  # convert dmDate from string to datetime
# get data from a specific team
gs_df = df1[['gmDate', 'gmTime', 'teamAbbr', 'teamLoc', 'teamRslt', 'opptAbbr', 'opptLoc','opptRslt']][(df1.teamAbbr == 'GS')]
gs_df.shape
    (492, 8)
gs_df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='gmDate', freq='BA-SEP')).groups
    {Timestamp('2013-09-30 00:00:00', freq='BA-SEP'): 82,
     Timestamp('2014-09-30 00:00:00', freq='BA-SEP'): 164,
     Timestamp('2015-09-30 00:00:00', freq='BA-SEP'): 246,
     Timestamp('2016-09-30 00:00:00', freq='BA-SEP'): 328,
     Timestamp('2017-09-29 00:00:00', freq='BA-SEP'): 410,
     Timestamp('2018-09-28 00:00:00', freq='BA-SEP'): 492}
```

Here we can see the grouping is actually a cumulative grouping whereas I'd like each group to have 82 rows

What would be the best approach to do this split?

Thanks for your feedbacks

S,

Comment: Can you share an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in this situation, I would like to make a column with the actual season in it, like season 2017 for example, and then make a multiindex using season, team, games. With this approach, you can slice and dice the data however you wish.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.read_csv('2012-18_teamBoxScore.csv')

# convert dmDate from string to datetime
df1['gmDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['gmDate'])  

# list of start dates, and the end date to the last year
dates = [
    "2012-09-30",
    "2013-09-30",
    "2014-09-30",
    "2015-09-30",
    "2016-09-30",
    "2017-09-29",
    "2018-09-28",
    "2019-09-28",
]

# make dates datetime
dates = pd.to_datetime(dates)

seasons = ['2012', '2013', '2014', '2015', '2016', '2017', '2018']

# create a season column using cut
df1['season'] = pd.cut(df1['gmDate'], dates, labels=seasons)

# a multiindex is easier to work with
df1.set_index(['teamAbbr', 'season', 'gmDate'], inplace=True)

columns = ['gmTime', 'teamLoc', 'teamRslt', 'opptAbbr', 'opptLoc','opptRslt']

# use an [index slicer][1] to get whatever data you want.
idx = pd.IndexSlice
df1.loc[idx[['CLE', 'DAL'], ['2012', '2014'], slice(None)],columns].head(2)
```

For result:

```
                              gmTime  teamLoc  teamRslt opptAbbr opptLoc opptRslt
teamAbbr    season  gmDate                      
CLE          2012   2012-10-30  19:00   Home    Win       WAS     Away    Loss
DAL          2012   2012-10-30  22:30   Away    Win       LAL     Home    Loss


# if you want to see all seasons or all teams, just replace with slice(None)
df1.loc[idx[['CLE'], slice(None), slice(None)],columns]

                      gmTime teamLoc teamRslt opptAbbr opptLoc opptRslt
teamAbbr season gmDate                      
CLE 2012    2012-10-30  19:00   Home    Win     WAS     Away    Loss
            2012-11-02  19:30   Home    Loss    CHI     Away    Win
            2012-11-03  20:30   Away    Loss    MIL     Home    Win
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, i was also thinking that the only to do this was by adding an extra column

Comment: Sometime go with your gut feeling... ☺

Answer (score 1):

You could use the pandas cut method as explained here [Pandas Groupby Range of Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21441259/pandas-groupby-range-of-values) . You might need to convert the dates to a numeric timestamp though prior to using the cut function.