# numpy.arange – 0 in data not reflected in range with start = 0

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have column in Pandas df (dtype = int64) which has a range of percentage values from 0% to 100%, spread over 80k rows.

I want to divide this data to groups of 5% so: `(0.0, 5.0], (5.0, 10.0], (10.0, 15.0] … (95, 100]`.

Based on suggestion in [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21441259/pandas-groupby-range-of-values) I have used `np.arange` to achieve this:

```
df['percentage_groups'] = pd.cut(df['percentage'], np.arange(0, 100+5, 5))
```

It works OK except that range `(0.0, 5.0]` is missing i.e. `np.nan` value is listed instead:

[image]

I have tried with `np.arange(0.0, 100+5, 5)` and this did not help. I only got 0 included when using this: `np.arange(-1, 100+5, 5)`. But this gives me `(-1, 4]` range, which does not look well in final results to present. Is there a way to include `0` in `0.0, 5.0` range?

Also if anyone knows how to make default range labels more nicely formatted i.e. `[...]` instead of `(...]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it is a bit problem, if bins are closed right (`]`). Solution is add `include_lowest=True` in [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) for adding label, but it is also less like `0`.

But if use labels parameetr, you can change data like need:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'percentage':[0,0,1,1,2,2,5,5,8,8,100]})

bins = np.arange(0, 100+5, 5)
labels = ['[{} - {}]'.format(i, j) for i, j in zip(bins[:-1], bins[1:])] 
labels[0] = '[{} - {}]'.format(bins[0], bins[1])

df['percentage_groups_orig'] = pd.cut(df['percentage'], bins = bins, include_lowest=True)
df['percentage_groups'] = (pd.cut(df['percentage'], 
                                  bins = bins, include_lowest=True, labels = labels))
print (df)
    percentage percentage_groups_orig percentage_groups
0            0          (-0.001, 5.0]           [0 - 5]
1            0          (-0.001, 5.0]           [0 - 5]
2            1          (-0.001, 5.0]           [0 - 5]
3            1          (-0.001, 5.0]           [0 - 5]
4            2          (-0.001, 5.0]           [0 - 5]
5            2          (-0.001, 5.0]           [0 - 5]
6            5          (-0.001, 5.0]           [0 - 5]
7            5          (-0.001, 5.0]           [0 - 5]
8            8            (5.0, 10.0]          [5 - 10]
9            8            (5.0, 10.0]          [5 - 10]
10         100          (95.0, 100.0]        [95 - 100]
```

You can also closed left by `right=False` parameter, but then problem is with last `100` value:

```
df['percentage_groups_orig'] = pd.cut(df['percentage'], bins = bins, include_lowest=True)
df['percentage_groups_left'] = pd.cut(df['percentage'], bins = bins, right=False)
print (df)
    percentage percentage_groups_orig percentage_groups_left
0            0          (-0.001, 5.0]             [0.0, 5.0)
1            0          (-0.001, 5.0]             [0.0, 5.0)
2            1          (-0.001, 5.0]             [0.0, 5.0)
3            1          (-0.001, 5.0]             [0.0, 5.0)
4            2          (-0.001, 5.0]             [0.0, 5.0)
5            2          (-0.001, 5.0]             [0.0, 5.0)
6            5          (-0.001, 5.0]            [5.0, 10.0)
7            5          (-0.001, 5.0]            [5.0, 10.0)
8            8            (5.0, 10.0]            [5.0, 10.0)
9            8            (5.0, 10.0]            [5.0, 10.0)
10         100          (95.0, 100.0]                    NaN
```

Comment: When reading doc for "np.arange" I haven't seen "include_lowest" but now I've checked "pandas.cut" doc and I see it there :)

Comment: Many thanks for support. I would not have done it so nicely (label formatting etc.) like you proposed.