# How to assign label and group by?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having this DF

```
short = data_set[['length', 'label']]

print(short)
```

```
        length label
0            6   Bad
1            2   Bad
2            3   Bad
3            8  Good
4            1   Bad
...        ...   ...
110030       9   Bad
110031      35  Good
110032       9   Bad
110033       2   Bad
110034      15  Good
```

I would like to group the values from the col `length` by range assigning a label to each range group i.e.

```
sum  range

20   0-10

5    10-20

...  ...
```

Suggestions?

Comment: have you looked into `pd.cut` ?

Comment: what is `sum` column indicates?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21441259/pandas-groupby-range-of-values

Comment: df.groupby(pd.cut(df["length"], np.arange(0,df["length"].max()+1,10))

Comment: Assuming that the linked question only *half* answers yours because you actually want a nicely formatted label, you can run: `grouped['label'] = grouped.apply(lambda row: f'{row.name.left} - {row.name.right}', axis=1)` on your `grouped` output dataframe

Comment: Do you discard the data for `label` column in original data? Means the "Bad", "Good" data.

Comment: You can try `df.groupby(pd.cut(df["length"], np.arange(0,df["length"].max(),10))).sum()`