# Can pandas groupby implement that groupping element to a arrary bucket?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

The `df_trace` which representes many bikes trace in a city, and `df_trace` likes this:

```
         LATITUDE   LONGITUDE
0        24.521047  118.161504
1        24.520763  118.161702
2        24.520385  118.162053
3        24.519880  118.162450
4        24.519403  118.162808
...            ...         ...
2504933  24.513834  118.167296
2504934  24.548244  118.101738
2504935  24.548293  118.101706
2504936  24.534143  118.096402
2504937  24.610413  118.113175
```

So I want to group trace to array bucket, and the array bucket can be seen as grid of this city.And the array bucket is a `100 * 100` grid, each cell of grid representes a region which can be griddinglize by the city region, so in this case each cell size is `(max_longitude - min_longitude) / 100` by `(max_latitude - min_latitude) / 100`:

```
bucket = [
  [[], [], ..., []],
  [[], [], ..., []],
  ...
  [[], [], ..., []]
]
```

The element of `df_trace` should be put into a cell of above grid, and the element longitude and latitude within the region of each cell. So can pandas groupby implement that?

Comment: You may be interested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21441259/pandas-groupby-range-of-values for the first part of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `pd.cut` will do what you want.  An example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# generate random walk (bike) trajectory
x = np.cumsum(np.random.normal(size=100000)).reshape(-1,1)
y = np.cumsum(np.random.normal(size=100000)).reshape(-1,1)
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.hstack([x,y]), columns=["x", "y"])

# define lat/long regions
N = 10
xbins = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), N)
ybins = np.linspace(y.min(), y.max(), N)
df["lon"] = pd.cut(df.x, bins=xbins)
df["lat"] = pd.cut(df.y, bins=ybins)

# now you can groupby each lat/lon and do some operation, e.g. count points:
df.groupby(["lat","lon"]).count().sort_values("x", ascending=False)

                                               x      y
lat                 lon
(-40.524, 8.152]    (502.077, 613.429]  10510  10510
(-89.201, -40.524]  (724.782, 836.134]   6787   6787
(-40.524, 8.152]    (613.429, 724.782]   5873   5873
(-137.877, -89.201] (836.134, 947.486]   5073   5073
(-89.201, -40.524]  (613.429, 724.782]   5025   5025
```

[image]

Comment: It seems that the `lat/lon` lost precision after pandas handled the walk (bike) trajectory.

Comment: unlikely - it's probably just how it's printed to terminal

Comment: Does `df.groupby(["lat","lon"]).count()` can count according to labels.It got a `TypeError: count() got an unexpected keyword argument 'level'` after tried `df.groupby(["lat","lon"]).count(level="bike_id")`

Comment: May be `df.groupby(["lat","lon"]).agg(["count"])` implement it.