# Pandas - Reshape Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, reshape

I have the following dataframe:

```
  Time  AreaIn  AreaOut   Output
0   1    Area E  Area G    200
1   16   Area E  Area G    200
2   31   Area E  Area G    200
3   46   Area E  Area G    300
4   61   Area E  Area G    459
5   ...  ...     ...       ...
93  1396 Area E  Area G    600
94  1411 Area E  Area G    400   
95  1426 Area E  Area G    500   
96  1441 Area E  Area G    500    
97  1    Area H  Area F    600
98  16   Area H  Area F    600
99  31   Area H  Area F    600
100 46   Area H  Area F    600
101 61   Area H  Area F    116
102 ...  ...     ...       ...
189 1381 Area H  Area F    111
190 1396 Area H  Area F    600   
191 1411 Area H  Area F    600   
192 1426 Area H  Area F    400
193 1441 Area H  Area F    400
```

And I want to reshape it. The column 'Time' ranges from 1 to 1441 with 15 interval, but I want it to range from 1 to 1441 with 60 interval. While the 'Output' should be the average of every 4 rows (sum of every 4 rows divided by 4).

In this case the dataframe contains only two time series so the result should look like this:

```
   Time   AreaIn  AreaOut   Output
0   1     Area E  Area G    450
1   61    Area E  Area G    500
2   121   Area E  Area G    600
3   181   Area E  Area G    892
4   241   Area E  Area G    459
5   ...    ...     ...       ...
21  1261  Area E  Area G    810
22  1321  Area E  Area G    598   
23  1381  Area E  Area G    650   
24  1441  Area E  Area G    250    
25  1     Area H  Area F    600
26  61    Area H  Area F    987
27  121   Area H  Area F    0
28  181    Area H  Area F   211
29  241    Area H  Area F   116
30  ...    ...     ...      ...
44  1201   Area H  Area F   111
45  1261   Area H  Area F   332   
46  1321   Area H  Area F   551   
47  1381   Area H  Area F   726
49  1441   Area H  Area F   250
```

However, I want to implement a generic solution that could work with more than two timeseries.

while using: `df = df.groupby(pd.cut(df["Time"], np.arange(1, 1442, 60))).mean()` I am getting the following result:

```
                 Time   Output
Time                         
(1, 61]           38.5   2351
(61, 121]         98.5   2752
(121, 181]        158.5  4323
(181, 241]        218.5  2523
(241, 301]        278.5  3456
(301, 361]        338.5  1653
(361, 421]        398.5  4361
(421, 481]        458.5  6543
(481, 541]        518.5  3245
(541, 601]        578.5  2434
(601, 661]        638.5  1387
(661, 721]        698.5  4456
(721, 781]        758.5  2534
(781, 841]        818.5  3424
(841, 901]        878.5  2376
(901, 961]        938.5  2656
(961, 1021]       998.5  3456
(1021, 1081]     1058.5  1212
(1081, 1141]     1118.5  3355
(1141, 1201]     1178.5  2466
(1201, 1261]     1238.5  3462
(1261, 1321]     1298.5  2344
(1321, 1381]     1358.5  2453
(1381, 1441]     1418.5  3256
```

Which groups the outputs of the two different time series and mixes up Area E - Area G with Area H - Area F. So I would like to keep those two time series separately.

Comment: What have you tried so far based on your own research, and what went wrong with your attempts? For example, pandas `resample` or `rolling` methods seem applicable

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Groupby Range of Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21441259/pandas-groupby-range-of-values)

Comment: @G.Anderson I have tried so far df.groupby, but this results in a dataframe with only two columns ['Time', 'Output'] without the 'AreaIn' and 'AreaOut' columns.  While I get the desirable results for the 'Output' the 'Time' column is not indexed properly.

Comment: @AlexisG I do not think that is what I am looking for. I don't want to group the 'Output' into bins. Just re-index the 'Time' column and average the 'Output' value.

Comment: if you do a group_by with bins of a range 60, it will regroup values from 1 to 60 in the same bin, values from 60 to 120 in another one ... And while going the groupby, you can use `mean()` to average the column `Output`

Comment: @AlexisG I added in the description the result I am getting when I am using `df = df.groupby(pd.cut(df["Time"], np.arange(1, 1442, 60))).mean()` , which is not what I am looking for as I am getting the mean of the two time series together.

Comment: you can use `agg()` to specify for each field the aggregation method for each fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us divide the time column by `60` to create a series which identifies the rows which falls into different 60 minutes intervals then `group` the dataframe by this series along with `AreaIn` and `AreaOut` and aggregate column `Time` using `first` and `output` using `mean` to get the desired result

```
s = df['Time'] // 60
df_out = df.groupby([s, 'AreaIn', 'AreaOut'], sort=False)\
           .agg({'Time': 'first', 'Output': 'mean'}).droplevel(0)
```

Comment: Thank you! Just for my own better understanding, how is it that the df_out gives only 24 positions for each time series, since the series I created has 4 points for each position? 
`0       0\
1       0\
2       0\
3       0\
4       1\
5       1\
6       1\
7       1\
...      ...\
92     23\
93     23\
94     23\
95     23\
96     24`

Comment: Since I want to concatenate vertically the df_out with another dataframe that had originally the 60 minutes intervals, would it be possible to re-order the columns in a way that they appear as in the original dataframe? If I try to use `df_out.reindex(columns=['Time', 'AreaIn', 'AreaOut', 'Output'])` the `'AreaIn'` and `'AreaOut'` appear with `NaNs`. As it seems that the `'Time', 'AreaIn', 'AreaOut'` are being used as an index.

Comment: @Pythoneer You can use `df_out = df_out.reset_index()`

Comment: @Pythoneer For your first question, I'll get back to you in sometime.

Comment: resetting the index `.reset_index()` first and then re-indexing `.reindex` worked as intended :)